# AngularJS get data from webapi and store in table

Tags: html, angularjs, json, rest

I created a rest web api and using AngularJS, I want to receive those json data and store them in a table. I am new to AngularJS. I was able to get all the json data but I want to split them up into each row. I am not sure if I am doing to correctly or not but here is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Angular</title>
<script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
<script src="angularDemo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="demoController">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Question</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat=" quiz values">
                <td>{{result.id}}</td> <!-- Does not get any value-->
                <td>{{result.question}}</td> <!-- Does not get any value-->
            </tr>
        </table>
        <h1>{{result}}</h1> <!-- gets all the json data -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module("demoApp", []);

app.controller("demoController", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/quiz/webapi/quiz")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.result = response.data;
    });
});
```

Comment: What is this `<tr ng-repeat=" quiz values">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ng-repeat` is not good,

If i understand your array of results is in `$scope.result`, so you have to do this kind of `ng-repeat` :

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in result">
   <td>{{row.id}}</td> 
   <td>{{row.question}}</td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: Oh ok I thought after ng-repeat="", it is supposed to be some kind of comments. Now I see, thank you